# Изменение css с помощью jQuery и сохранение результата

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, css

Есть код, который меняет css по клику на кнопку, но при обновлении страницы css естественно становиться прежним. Есть ли возможность сохранить изменение в файл? Просто насколько я знаю, js не работает с файлами, тогда можно ли с помощью php получить данные о нажатии на кнопку, а потом записать в файл?

Comment: скажите конкретно что именно вам нужно... вашу конкретную задачу... может это можно решить другим способом...

Comment: Есть js код:
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#social").click(function() {
$("#image").animate({
marginLeft: ".1%"
}, 1500 );
});
 });
</script>

нужно что бы изменение margin-left записывалось в файл index.html в тег <style></style>, и при нажатии на кнопку было не просто ".1%" а "(Значение, которое уже есть + .1%"

Comment: ИМХО, аякс + сессия. А названия класса лучше поменять.

Comment: Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var img = $('#image');
    img.css('margin-left', localStorage.getItem('image-pos') || 0);

    $('#social').click(function(e) {
        img.animate({'margin-left': '+=50px'}, 1500, function() {
            localStorage.setItem('image-pos', img.css('margin-left'));
        });
    });
});
```

Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то можно сохранять в куки или сессию.

Comment: Сделал так:

    $(function() {
    var img = $('#image');
    img.css('margin-left', localeStorage.getItem('image-pos') || 0);
    $('#social').click(function(e) {
    img.animate({
    marginLeft: "20%"
    }, 1500, function() {
    localeStorage.setItem('image-pos', img.css('margin-left'));
    });
    });
    });

не работает, в чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Поправил, теперь должно работать.